# Custom cell editor for input type file in tabulator

Tags: javascript, node.js, tabulator

I am trying to integrate **custom editor** for input type file(image).

```
editor: fileEditor,
```

and a function is there called fileEditor

```
var fileEditor = function (cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams) {
    var cellId = cell.getRow().getData()._id;
    
    var uploadTo = document.createElement("input");
    uploadTo.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    uploadTo.setAttribute("name", "uploadTo");
    uploadTo.setAttribute("id", "uploadTo");
    uploadTo.setAttribute("value", "images/category");

    var editor = document.createElement("input");
    editor.setAttribute("type", "file");
    editor.setAttribute("name", "imgFile");
    editor.setAttribute("id", cellId+"_imgFile");
    editor.style.padding = "3px";
    editor.style.width = "100%";
    editor.style.boxSizing = "border-box";
    
    onRendered(function () {
        editor.focus();
        editor.style.css = "100%";
    });
    function successFunc() {
        console.log(cell, editor.value)
        if(editor.value != ""){
            // cell.setValue(editor.value, true)
            success(editor.value);
            updateCategoryImage(cell, cell.getColumn().getField(), cell.getRow().getData()._id)
        }else{
            cell.cancelEdit();
        }
    }
    editor.addEventListener("change", successFunc);
    return editor;
};
```

and in updateCategoryImage() i am trying to upload this image to s3 using formdata but the file element is not presesnt in DOM. Please help me out for solve this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The element will be destroyed as soon as the editor has triggered the success function *(it is then imediatly replaced with the cells value)*, so you should call your `updateCategoryImage` function before you call `success`